# HTA Self-Modifying Code?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'd like to try to make an HTA that holds some data between sessions.  The file might move from one computer to another, so I don't want to depend on cookies, and it won't have some remote server to save data to, so my hope is to find a way to use scripting like vbscript to write the save data back to the HTA itself, so that the next time the application runs, it already has the latest information.

What I'd likely do is dedicate a run of lines in the code as a list of variable declarations that will be used to initialize the application.  There would be some kind of "save" button in the application that will read the current state of those variables and edit the hta file's source code, specifically on those lines and replace the values with whatever the current values are.

Since an HTA file is essentially just a text file with a different extension, I would assume there's a way to have the HTA edit itself like any other file...but I don't actually know how to do it, or how to isolate the lines of code where the variables will reside and edit them without having to load the entire file into memory and save the entire thing each time I want to save something... I'd like to keep things completely self-contained, so I don't want to depend on external files like an XML or CSV to store settings between sessions, so I'd like to be able to embed the data into the HTA.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed modify an HTA file while it's running because it's interpreted code. Same way you can modify an HTML file while you're viewing in your browser.

However, I would not do it that way unless there is some compelling reason you must keep everything in 1 file. **If there is a problem writing to the HTA, you will end up with a blank file and lose everything.** Therefore, I recommend using a plain text file to store your data and include that with your HTA.

**MyApp.hta**:

```
<!doctype html>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="MyApp"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  ICON=""
  ID="HTA"
  INNERBORDER="no"
  NAVIGABLE="no"
  SCROLL="yes"
  SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
  VERSION="0.0.1"
/>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: Calibri, Arial; font-size: 20px; }
    label { font-weight: bold; }
    .settings__container { position: relative; height: 200px; border: 2px dashed #ccc; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 2px; }
    #settings { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Settings:</label>
  <div class="settings__container">
    <textarea id="settings"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="save-settings__button">Save Now</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var settingsElement = document.getElementById('settings'),
          settingsFile = "MyApp.settings.txt",
          io = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

      function loadSettings() {
        try {
          var file = io.OpenTextFile(settingsFile, 1),
              data = file.ReadAll();

          file.Close();
          settingsElement.value = data;
        } catch(e) {
          // Failed to load settings; settings file may not exist yet.
        }
      }

      function saveSettings(data) {
        var file = io.OpenTextFile(settingsFile, 2, true);
        file.Write(data);
        file.Close();
      }

      // Assuming IE9+
      document.getElementById('save-settings__button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        saveSettings(settingsElement.value);
      });

      // Load the settings file
      addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        loadSettings();
      });

      // Save the settings on exit
      addEventListener('unload', function(e) {
        saveSettings(settingsElement.value);
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.84).aspx). If you're using vbscript, you would need to

- Open the HTA file with [OpenTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx)
- Read the file
- Modify the lines you want changed
- Write the new contents to the file with [CreateTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx) (Overwrite set to True)

For using Javascript the procedure is the same, the methods are slightly different.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I wanted to make sure... If I try to modify the HTA file while it's already open, will it be able to save, or will it show that the file is locked?  I think IE opens files as read-only, and as such doesn't lock the files except when they're first loaded into memory, so I assume I can safely save over the HTA while it's already open, but I'd like to be sure before I go writing a bunch of code that can't work.